# Click the annotation and change color

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit

I want to change the anntation color when user click it . my code just like that

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:view.annotation reuseIdentifier:@"annon1"];
[annotationView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
[annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
[innerMap selectAnnotation:annotationView.annotation animated:YES];
}
```

but is not work for me . anyone can help me ??

Comment: Is the delegate call even being made. If you put a log in that method, is it printed. You may have forgotten to set the delegate.

Comment: @Bergasms i have already set delegate just like "[myMap setDelegate:self]"; anything i need to change on my code ??

Comment: @Bergasms I have already fix this problem .. Thants